# Mysql 5.6.21 Unauthenticated user with state reading from net

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage, processlist

The cpu usage is very high when mysql authenticate user. I have also tried using --skip-name-resolve but didn't work for me. Please see the screenshot below when I show processlist on mysql command.

[image]

Please help !

Thanks!